# error[E0277]: expected a `std::ops::FnOnce<(&select::node::Node<'_>,)>` closure, found `select::predicate::Class<&&str>`

Tags: rust

I met the error If I write the code as below ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=956135d0d2b6954752755e3cd725efa0)):

```rust
use select::document::Document;
use select::node::Node;
use select::predicate::Class;
use std::fmt;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main()-> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>>{
    let mut info: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
    let mut url = fmt::format(format_args!(
        "https://github.com/{}?page={}&tab=following",
        "dr-guangtou", 1
    ));
    let mut body = reqwest::get(&url).await?.text().await?;
    let mut body_str: &str = &body;

    let mut document = Document::from(body_str);
    let mut node2: Option<Node>;
    let class_name :[&str; 4]= [
        "p-org",
        "p-label",
        "js-user-profile-bio",
        "text-gray-darkerline",
    ];
    for tag in &class_name {
        node2 = document.find(Class(tag)).take(1).next();
        if node2.is_some() {
        info.push(node2.unwrap().text().to_owned());
        } 
        else {
            info.push("Null".to_owned());
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

my current workaround is

```rust
...
let mut cnt = 0;
for tag in &class_name {
    node2 = document.find(Class(class_name[cnt])).take(1).next();
    if node2.is_some() {
       info.push(node2.unwrap().text().to_owned());
    } 
    else {
        info.push("Null".to_owned());
    }
    cnt +=1;
}
```

which I can't explain why it works, I want to know the reason behind this problem.

Comment: @eggyal You're right, I should be serious and obey the rules for asking a question

Comment: @eggyal I'm working on providing a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Great, thanks!  I've added a playground link for you.  And also removed the [tag:select] tag, as that's related to the `SELECT` operation in SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Document::find` takes a value that implements `Predicate`, so the type of `Class(tag)` must implement `Predicate`. As @kmdreko mentioned below, [`Predicate` is only defined for `Class<&str>`](https://docs.rs/select/0.5.0/select/predicate/trait.Predicate.html#impl-Predicate-6); thus `tag` must be of type `&str`.

However, `tag` is a `&&str` as `class_name`, which is an array of `&str`s, is being iterated over by reference. The auto deref rules do not apply in this case as the type parameter of the `Class` constructor is not explicitly specified, and the compiler simply infers the type parameter to be the type (`&&str`) of the argument (`tag`). Hence the type of `Class(tag)` is `Class<&&str>` and not `Class<&str>`.

In order to make it a `Class<&str>`, you'll have to manually dereference `tag` once, either by passing `Class(*tag)` as the argument to `document.find` or during declaration in the for loop with `for &tag in &class_name`. A third option is to explicitly specify the `Class` type parameter with `Class::<&str>(tag)`, in which the compiler automatically dereferences `tag` from a `&&str` to a `&str`.

`Class(class_name[cnt])` works is because `class_name[cnt]` indexes the array by *value*, which yields a copy of the `&str` reference at index `cnt` in `class_name`. Hence `class_name[cnt]` is of type `&str`, and `Class(class_name[cnt])` is of type `Class<&str>`.

Comment: I think this answer is missing the crucial first step of explaining that `Class<&str>` is required because [`Predicate` is only defined for `Class<&str>`](https://docs.rs/select/0.5.0/select/predicate/trait.Predicate.html#impl-Predicate-6) and not any other type.

Comment: Thanks @kmdreko! I've edited the answer to include this.